# C++ Line graph acting funky

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to create a line graph that displays temperatures that have been read from a local file. Currently, everything is working as intended except the graphical output.

Right now, my `else` statement for the negative numbers is not working correctly. In addition, some numbers appear to be shown and some do not.

Lastly, the numbers that are displaying are not showing the right number of '*". I know I am close but cannot crack the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std

int main()
{

//Variable declarations
int numberOfStars;
int printStars;
int temp;
int count = 0; 
string lineBreak = " | "; 



ifstream tempData;
tempData.open("tempData.txt");

cout << "Temperatures for 24 hours: " << endl;
cout << "   -30      0      30      60      90      120" << endl;

printStars = 0;

while (count < 24) {
    tempData >> temp;

    if (temp >= 0) {
        numberOfStars = temp / 3;
        cout << setw(4) << temp << setw(10) << lineBreak;

        while (printStars < numberOfStars){
            cout << '*';
            printStars++;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;

    }

    else {
        numberOfStars = temp / 3;

        while (numberOfStars > printStars) {
            cout << '*';
            printStars++;
        }
        cout << setw(4) << temp << setw(10)<< lineBreak << endl << endl;

    }

    count++;

}

//Closing program statements
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Currently it is outputting:

[image: Output]

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you understand that `temp` must be negative, in order for the `else` branch to be taken? Because that's what the `if` statement says. So, if `temp` is negative, pop quiz: do you think that `temp / 3` will be positive or negative? You know that `printStars` must be positive, so what do you think are the chances of `while (numberOfStars > printStars)` being true?

Comment: Yeah I understand that temp must be negative for the else statement to execute. I guess I just do not understand the logic. This is what I understand is happening. -21 / 3 = -7. So, while (-7 > 0) print a '*'. So since it is less nothing occurs. Yet, when I switch the while statement to while (numberOfStars < printStars) I get an infinite look of '*' being printed.

Answer (score 1):

Oh just put your `printStars = 0;` in the while :)

And do `numberOfStars = temp / 3 + 1;` if you want to have one star for temp < 3.

**EDIT:** You can simplify a lot your code. You can create a string with n time a character very easily. Your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

//Variable declarations
int numberOfStars;
int numberOfSpaces;
int temp;
int count = 0; 
string lineBreak = " | "; 
ifstream tempData;
tempData.open("data.txt");

cout << "Temperatures for 24 hours: " << endl;
cout << "   -30      0      30      60      90      120" << endl;

while (count < 24) {
    tempData >> temp;
    numberOfStars = temp / 3 + 1;

    if (temp >= 0) {
        cout << setw(4) << temp << setw(10) << lineBreak;
        cout << string(numberOfStars, '*');
    }
    else {
        cout << setw(4) << temp;
        numberOfSpaces = 7 + numberOfStars;

        // Prevent any ugly shift
        if (numberOfSpaces < 0)
        {
            numberOfSpaces = 0;
            numberOfStars = -7;
        }

        cout << string(7 + numberOfStars, ' ');
        cout << string(-numberOfStars, '*');
        cout << lineBreak;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    count++;

}

//Closing program statements
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```